# Gutenberg: How to use output of php render_callback function in the block editors backend?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I tried to write a very simple block plugin for Gutenberg: A simple TOC generator. I can now place a block in a post and the table of contents is being generated as an unordered list. Great! But in the backend (Gutenberg Editor) there is still my ugly block that just say "SimpleTOC" and is not dynamic.

How can I display the output of my php function "render_callback" in the plugin.php https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/0.5/plugin.php in the "edit" function in the JS code? I read my tutorials and looked at core blocks but I just don't get the server side functions.

This is all of my index.js https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/0.5/src/index.js block code:

```
const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'simpletoc/toc', {
    title: __( 'Table of Contents', 'simpletoc' ),
    icon: 'list-view',
    category: 'layout',
    edit( { className } ) {
    return <p className={ className }>
        <ul>
            <li>SimpleTOC</li>
            <li>SimpleTOC</li>
            <li>SimpleTOC</li>
        </ul>
        </p>;
  },
    save: props => {
        return null;
    },
} );
```

My render_callback function looks like this in plugin.php https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/0.5/plugin.php:

```
function render_callback( $attributes, $content ) {

    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content( get_the_ID()));

    if ( empty( $blocks ) ) {
        return 'No contents.';
    }

  //add only if block is used in this post.
  add_filter( 'render_block', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_block', 10, 2 );

    $headings = array_values( array_filter( $blocks, function( $block ){
        return $block['blockName'] === 'core/heading';
    }) );
    if ( empty( $headings ) ) {
        return 'No headings.';
    }

    $heading_contents = array_column( $headings, 'innerHTML');

    $output .= '<ul class="toc">';
    foreach ( $heading_contents as $heading_content ) {
        preg_match( '|<h[^>]+>(.*)</h[^>]+>|iU', $heading_content , $matches );

        $link = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $matches[1]);
        $output .= '<li><a href="#' . $link . '">' . $matches[1] . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add serversiderender as a component in php (in init), package.js and the js code.

init in php

```
  wp_register_script(
    'simpletoc',
    plugins_url('build/index.js', __FILE__),
    [ 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-server-side-render' ],
    filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'build/index.js')
    );
```

block js:

```
const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';

registerBlockType( 'simpletoc/toc', {
    title: __( 'SimpleTOC', 'simpletoc' ),
    icon: 'list-view',
    category: 'layout',
    edit: function( props ) {
        return (
                    <p className={ props.className }>
            <ServerSideRender
                block="simpletoc/toc"
                attributes={ props.attributes }
            />
                    </p>
        );
    },
    save: props => {
        return null;
    },
} );
```

and install it in the environment:

```
npm install @wordpress/server-side-render --save
```

I forgot the very first step and then it just worked. Complete working script here: https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/tree/0.6

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are missing the PHP registration of the block.

The JS definition is all right, but you need to tell PHP that the block exists.

Can you try to register your block in your plugin or function.php file?

Here is an example https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/

```php
<?php

function simpletoc_toc_render_callback( $attributes, $content ) {
    return 'This is my block content'.
}

function simpletoc_toc_register_block() {
    register_block_type( 'simpletoc/toc', array(
        'render_callback' => 'simpletoc_toc_render_callback'
    ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'simpletoc_toc_register_block' );
```

Note that the code above is shortened to the essential.

**EDIT** Sorry, didn't realized that all the magic for the backend rendering was coming from ACF Plugin.

You might want to have a look at this.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-server-side-render/ Though I have no idea on how to use it.